# Move n number of files from one directory to another using PHP

Tags: php, file

Is there a way to move certain number of files in a directory to another using PHP script?

I mean to say there are some 500 files in a directory, I need to transfer first 100 files to another directory.

Using for/foreach loop to move the file & getting the count of every file is bit lengthy process. Looking for some better solution.

Can anyone help me in this please..

Comment: Is it just any 100 files, do you have a list of them or should it be the first 100 alphabetically?

Comment: @ToreØstergaard - not any 100, what ever the order that we have in the directory..the first 'n' number from there..more like how you get in a loop

Comment: How lengthy are you talking? I have moved a lot of files before and it didn't seem to take too long.